# prepend/append works in Chrome and Firefox but not IE11 and Edge

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, prepend

Trying to prepend data inside a text box in Chrome and Firefox works.
Get error:  SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'prepend' 
in IE11 and Edge. Thx

```
    function init_TGs(){
        if (confirm("Initialize TinyG's?")){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "init_TGs", 
                data: 'None',
                success: function(result){
                    if (result != ''){
                        var rslt= result;
                        var item = document.getElementById('TextArea1');
                        item.prepend(rslt);
                    }}
                });
            }};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/prepend#Browser_compatibility
Prepend doesn't have support for IE and edge.
Instead of Prepend just try to rewrite the business logic with some other function.

Answer (score 24):

Or, instead of adding a new polyfill you can use `insertBefore` function which is [supported by all browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=insertBefore):

```
var rslt= result;
var item = document.getElementById('TextArea1');
item.insertBefore(rslt, item.childNodes[0]);
```

Answer (score 6):

IE and Edge does not support the javascript prepend method, so to make prepend method to work you need to use polyfill.

```
(function (arr) {
  arr.forEach(function (item) {
    if (item.hasOwnProperty('prepend')) {
      return;
    }
    Object.defineProperty(item, 'prepend', {
      configurable: true,
      enumerable: true,
      writable: true,
      value: function prepend() {
        var argArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
          docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();

        argArr.forEach(function (argItem) {
          var isNode = argItem instanceof Node;
          docFrag.appendChild(isNode ? argItem : document.createTextNode(String(argItem)));
        });

        this.insertBefore(docFrag, this.firstChild);
      }
    });
  });
})([Element.prototype, Document.prototype, DocumentFragment.prototype]);
```

usage

```
document.getElementById("some_id").prepend(Element-you-want-to-prepend)
```

for more info check

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/prepend#Polyfill

Answer (score -3):

ok, use jquery. Simple solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button-sel').on('click', function(event) {
        var targ = event.target.id;
        //alert("You clicked on: " + targ);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: targ, 
            data: 'none',
            success: function(result){
                if (result != ''){
                    var rslt= result;
                    $('#TextArea1').prepend(result);
            }}
        });
});})
```